# Encoding issue when save string "Donâ€™t do it" by ServiceStack and Ormlite to MySQL

Tags: mysql, .net, encoding, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Save object with string ***Donâ€™t do it*** by ServiceStack and OrmLite to MySQL.

The string changed to  ***DonÃ¢â‚¬â„¢t do it*** in MySQL.

If I read the value from MySQL and save again, then get ***DonÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢t do it***

It only happened on one Windows server 2016 with .net 4.62, it works correctly on other Windows with .net 4.62 and OSX with Mono.

ServiceStack libraries version is "4.5.0"; MySQL version is 5.6.23; The database table and column charset are UTF-8.

It may be somewhere do the wrong encoding escape and repeat it again and again. I upgraded from .net 4.5 to 4.62 recently.

I can not debug it: it works on developing MAC, and test Windows; it only failed in the production environment.

Comment: That's called "double encoding".  Even "triple encoding".  You are repeatedly treating the bytes as latin1, then converting to utf8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has sorted out:

It's from the MySQL connection string. We recently added the "**ConnectionReset=True;**" which triggered this encoding issue.

It will convert a UTF-8 string to be read as Western 1252 encoding; so a ***â€™*** will be displayed as ***Ã¢â‚¬â„¢***, and so on

It is able to reproduce on another Windows Server.

After setting it to false or remove it; it fixed.